# Can someone please explain this C++ code?

Tags: c++

`lists` is actually the name of `vector<ListNode*>`

```
lists.erase(remove_if(lists.begin(), lists.end(), [](ListNode* node){return !node;}),lists.end());
```

Comment: [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), [std::vector::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)

Comment: [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) see Examples for erase-remove idiom.

Comment: First you need to recognize the use of a lambda expression.  [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your `lists` variable is from this vector pointer, we can say:

[Erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) is being used to remove an element in range which is housed by the `remove_if` function.

```
lists.erase
```

You can find more information about `remove_if` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/).

This section of the function works by getting the starting element range and ending element range to fill the appropriate parameters of data necessary to erase:

```
lists.begin( ), // Note: Iterator finds starting element.
lists.end( ),   // Note: Iterator finds ending element.
[]( ListNode* node )
```

Note: This parameter `( ListNode* node )` after our capture is used to house our vector array pointer of `node` so that when node is passed, the return argument
is declared as invalid:

```
{ return !node; }
```

To finish the function, our `lists` variable will end with one more parameter to complete our node pointer ( ahead ) with another `.end( )` iterator:

```
), lists.end( ) );
```

If you want anymore information on iterators or vectors, check out these references:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/

Comment: _"the return argument is declared as invalid"_ Eh?